# Verification of Caching approach with EhCache, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

I have an application that implements a Socket connection to read positional data. Each position relates to an asset. The stream is updating positional data for the many hundreds of assets in real time. Here a a basic class representation of the 2 domain objects:

```
public class Asset{
    long id;
    Set<Position> positions;
}


public class Position{
    long id;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    Date timestamp
}
```

Now, I want the positional data for the last 1 day to be available to a remote client for polling. There will be many hundreds of clients making polling requests for the last day of positional data for each asset. Each asset will be updated with positional data every 5 seconds. The requirement is that the client request may be no more than 10 seconds out of sync with the real time update.

This is putting a huge load on the database - which is where EHCache comes in - maybe...

A nicer alternative (questionable!) would be to configure a cache into which any new Assets and associated Positions would be stored as they are read by the Socket Connection. This cache would expire any Asset that was updated more than a day ago and would be responsible for writing new Assets and Positions to the database periodically (every minute or so). Remote clients would hit the cache for Assets and Positional data.

I just wanted some thoughts / advice on whether this approach might be sensible and also which features of EHCache could facilitate it.

Many thanks

Comment: For additional information, the clients can only READ information from the resource. There is no writing. The only writing that should be done would be from the cache to the underlying resource.

Comment: As a starting point you might want to take a look at these articles about the 2nd level cache and the query cache: [1](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html), [2](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be a good use case for EhCache and Hibernate [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache). Here is the basic architecture. First, enable second level cache for `Position` object. I think it misses the `asset` field which represents one-to-many relationship, but it doesn't matter.

I assume clients are running query similar to this one:

```
SELECT p
FROM Position p
WHERE timestamp >= :timestamp
  AND asset = :assert
```

The `:timestamp` parameter represents the last 24 hours (current time - 24 hours). You need to enable `cacheable` query hint on this query.

Here's what happens: the client runs this query indirectly with a pair of `(asset, timestamp)` parameters. Hibernate tries to find a query result in query cache for this pair which (simplifying) makes up a query cache key.

If the query result is missing, it runs the query and puts results in the query cache. *But* it only places ids of matching `Position` instances, not the instances itself. The next time some client asks for the same pair of `(asset, timestamp)`, Hibernate will find the results in query cache. Then, having only ids, it will search for `Position` instances in second level cache.

As you can see this scenario is quite complex and several factors will influence the overall success:

- how many distinct pairs of `(asset, timestamp)` are there? Roughly:

.

```
86400 (number of different seconds in a day) times 
  number of different assets
```

keys and values must fit in cache. Remember that each value is a list of `Position` ids. That's a lot of memory. You can probably cut this by limiting the number of different timestamps. Is last 24 hours such important? Can that be *between 23 and 24 hours* or such? This way you can round timestamps and decrease the size of the key space (cache size).

- All `Position` instances references by id from query cache must fit in cache. This might be huge. But otherwise you will hit the `N + 1` problem, since in the absence of `Position` entity in L2 cache while fetching from query cache, Hibernate will perform implicit query by id from the database.
- Cache invalidation is performed by Hibernate. However remember that each insert to `Position` table will invalidate query cache. In your circumstances fully warming up the cache might never be possible.

That being said, you should give a try to query caching in Hibernate. However query cache is very tricky and requires a lot of tuning to implement correctly.

Tip: if you are running out of memory, try overflowing EhCache to disk. Never tried it, but I belive fetching serialized cache values from local disk (especially when SSD is used) *might* be much faster than cache miss and database query.

Comment: Concerning you tip: never tried overflowing EhCache to disk either, but I'd guess that providing more RAM to a well tuned database and do without the Hibernate cache altogether is faster than that. A well tuned database should have lots of cache hits anyway, on top of this I don't think that reading the EhCache from disk is faster than a database query from disk.

Comment: @Tomasz, thanks for your feedback. I have been reading quite a lot of negative press about the query cache feature for Hibernate - and how the memory overhead of storing key value pairs (like in this instance) quickly becomes significant. Additionally, the query result will be invalidated often if a table is regularly updated. Since the position table is updated every seconds, my cached queries will almost always be invalidated..

Comment: Is there not a case for ignoring hibernate caching altogether - implementing EHCache for Java objects instantiated at the socket and then using a cron task to update the tables from the java objects within the cache?